Principal components obtained from kernel principal component analysis.
I know that the principal components that we get when we do PCA on a dataset are linear combinations of the feature variables, but will that also be true if we apply kernel PCA on our dataset?
Will the principal components that I get when I apply kernel PCA still be a linear combination of our feature variables?
